# Create a sorted-map of coordinates

Tags: clojure

I wrote a little function to create a `sorted-map` with vectors of coordinates as keys and an empty map as a default value:

```clj
(defn empty-board [rows cols]
  (into (sorted-map) 
        (for [x (range cols) y (range rows)]
            [[x y] {}])))
```

Is there is a more idiomatic way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the right way to do it.

Many Clojure programs do not bother with creating empty maps. The absence of a value or `nil` behave like an empty map. For example `(assoc nil :foo :bar)` returns `{:foo :bar}`. You may be able to initialize to an empty `sorted-map`, and only `assoc-in` novelty as you need it ... depending on your logic.